# Jenkins pipeline - No such DSL method 'build'

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using below Groovy Script in Jenkins Pipeline to call a Free style job but it ends up with "No such DSL method 'build'" error.

```
node{
       def branches = [:] 
       List rows =["Test2", "Test1"] 
       for (int i = 0; i <rows.size(); i++) 
       { 
         def index = i  
         String db = rows[i] 
         branches["branch${i}"] = { 
             build job: 'CopyFile', parameters: [[$class:  
            'StringParameterValue', name:  'DatabaseName', value: db], [$class: 
            'StringParameterValue', name:'dummy', value: "${index}"]] 
       } 
   } 
   parallel branches
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, a similar (simplified) versions works as expected for me. Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1280)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1174)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1280)

Comment: at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1174)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:18)

Comment: at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Umm, unsure what the problem is here. However, it seems like the example above isn't what you are actually running considering `WorkflowScript:18` in the stacktrace, e.g. there are at-least 18 lines in the one you run, above script doesn't have 18 lines. Have you tried the script above?

Comment: When I posted, I removed the comments here the updated stack trace
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
 at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:9)

Comment: I was missing Pipeline Build Step plugin, and installing it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Installing "Pipeline Build Step Plugin" resolved this issue

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Build+Step+Plugin