# New to Jenkins; simple build fails with No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple hello world project which is failing on a new Jenkins install. I'm following the instructions in this URL: https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-hello-world

For reference, the following simple build pipeline plugins are installed:

Build Pipeline Plugin 1.5.8
Pipeline Keep Running Step 1.0
Pipeline Utility Steps 2.6.1
Pipeline: API 2.40
Pipeline: Basic Steps 2.22
Pipeline: Build Step 2.13
Pipeline: Groovy 2.85
Pipeline: Input Step 2.12
Pipeline: Job 2.40
Pipeline: Keep Environment Step Plugin 1.0
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes 2.36
Pipeline: REST API Plugin 2.18
Pipeline: SCM Step 2.11
Pipeline: Stage Step 2.5
Pipeline: Stage View Plugin 2.18
Pipeline: Step API 2.23
Pipeline: Supporting APIs 3.6
Lockable Resources

(so that also makes the following links I read before posting not applicable: [Jenkins pipeline - No such DSL method 'build'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118619/jenkins-pipeline-no-such-dsl-method-build), [Jenkins Pipeline - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'lock' found among steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713980/jenkins-pipeline-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-such-dsl-method-lock-found), [No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533900/no-such-dsl-method-pipeline-found-among-steps))

So per the tutorial I'm following, I created a pipeline,  and in the configuration put the following code in the "Pipeline" section:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello World!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the "Build Now" button, I get the following from the console output:

```
Started by user dogzilla
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, compareVersions, deleteDir, dir, echo, error, fileExists, findFiles, getContext, input, isUnix, junit, keepEnv, keepRunning, load, lock, mail, node, nodesByLabel, parallel, powershell, publishChecks, pwd, pwsh, readCSV, readFile, readJSON, readManifest, readMavenPom, readProperties, readYaml, retry, sh, sha1, sleep, stage, stash, step, tee, timeout, tm, tool, touch, unarchive, unstable, unstash, unzip, waitUntil, warnError, withContext, withEnv, wrap, writeCSV, writeFile, writeJSON, writeMavenPom, writeYaml, ws, zip] or symbols [all, always, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildDiscarders, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, command, credentials, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, envVars, envVarsFilter, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, fingerprints, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, javadoc, jdk, jdkInstaller, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName, junitTestResultStorage, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, mailer, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, myView, nodeProperties, none, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, permanent, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, resourceRoot, retainOnlyVariables, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, simpleBuildDiscarder, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sshPublicKey, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, timezone, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, userSeed, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, env, params]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:216)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Curious as to why this is failing.  If there's a java problem, Jenkins won't even start.  I have all the plugins installed that are in the instructions and some of the troubleshooting links I've read.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the answer while someone was helping me on a different forum.  Posting here in case it's useful to anyone else down the road.

In https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/, it says:

All valid Declarative Pipelines must be enclosed within a pipeline block, for example:

```
pipeline {

/* insert Declarative Pipeline here */

}
```

So when I wrapped the example script in pipeline {}, it works.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're missing a bunch of pipeline plugins. Make sure to install "Pipeline" (ID: workflow-aggregator), it will install other pipeline missing plugins.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator/#dependencies

Comment: Thanks.  I've gone to the pipeline manager and installed everything with the word pipeline in it.  Also, in that link you sent, most of those individual  plugins are no longer available or deprecated.